# Export FabricJS canvas to PNG/JPG with Images in it

Tags: fabricjs

This is my code to export canavs to Image using FabricJS:

```
window.open(canvas.toDataURL( {format: 'jpeg' }));
```

Code to add images is below:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('URL here', function(img) {
var oImg = img.set({ left: 50, top: 100,}).scale(0.5);
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
});
```

It works fine with Text and Shapes, but gives out of an .htm file when external images are added to the canvas.

No explicit errors, just the wrong output.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem or a code snippet?  Are there any errors in the console when you try your code?

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look now. There are no errors in the console though. Just a wrong output.

Comment: Try adding {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'} as the third argument of fromURL when adding the image.  If that doesn't work, have you looked at the text output of toDataURL?

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly. Thank you. But there is still a problem, I am setting up Canvas background using:
`canvas.setBackgroundColor({source:"Image source"},
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));` How can I add crossOrigin in Background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the background use `canvas.setBackgroundImage` instead.  You can provide a fabric image for it as the first argument, which, if loaded using the crossOrigin approach, should avoid the problem happening when you use a background.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/', handleImage, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});

function handleImage(img) {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    // do whatever extra needs to be done for the background
}
```

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

http://scanova.io/blog/engineering/2014/06/09/fabric-js-slow-rendering-issues-cors/